# Android How to update single row in listview?

Tags: android, listview

I have a List View and every item has pin button, that start service (downloading item).
Service send percents via broadcast, and I have to update pin button.
I'm trying to do it with getting view from List View and set value to pin button such as

```
int firstVisibleElement = postListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
int lastVisibleElement = postListView.getLastVisiblePosition();
if (position >= firstVisibleElement && position <= lastVisibleElement) {
     View view = postListView.getChildAt(lastVisibleElement - position);
    }
```

But when I scroll during sync, it return wrong view. 
How can I fix it?

Comment: [This might be the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953268/hide-custom-search-bar-if-all-items-in-adapter-are-showing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "conversion" from dataset position and "child view position" in `ListView` is wrong.

The children views in `ListView` are numbered from 0 to `listView.getChildCount() - 1`. A position in the dataset, as the variable `position` should be, goes from 0 to `adapter.getCount() - 1`. The method `listview.getFirstVisiblePosition()` returns the first *dataset* position that is visible on the screen, i.e. what dataset position corresponds to the 0th view in `ListView`.

Now say you have 15 items in your `Adapter`, you have 10 items in your `ListView` on screen, and you scrolled down by 2 items. This means the visible item positions in the dataset are from 2 to 11, but the "child view positions" are always from 0 to 9. `listview.getFirstVisiblePosition()` would return 2.

By mean of this example, it's easy to convert from "dataset position" to "child view position": the child view position is basically the dataset position minus the first visible dataset position:

```
int firstVisibleElement = postListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
int lastVisibleElement = postListView.getLastVisiblePosition();
if (position >= firstVisibleElement && position <= lastVisibleElement) {
    View view = postListView.getChildAt(position - firstVisibleElement);
}
```